# How to force mysql to rollback transaction on error

Tags: mysql, error-handling, transactions, rollback, mysql-5.7

We have a process where we need to test a SQL script before it runs against a production database.  The approach is to execute the script within a transaction with a rollback statement at the end, capturing before/after logs illuminating the effects of the scripts.

```
select now();

start transaction;

select 'data before any changes', ...;

<insert / update / delete statements>;

select 'data after changes', ...;

rollback;
```

We've used this approach for many years with MSSQL, however we're having trouble implementing with mysql.  If everything is working to-plan, things are great and it works exactly as expected.  However, if we run into any errors (ex: typo in SQL or table constraint violation), the script aborts ... but COMMITS whatever ran before the error!!

How is this remotely considered an acceptable outcome?  It drastically reduces the effectiveness of transactions if an error condition results in committing changes.  I'm gobsmacked at this behavior--simply cannot understand the rationale.

I've been searching all over for a resolution to this and am coming up basically empty-handed.  Options I've seen:

1. Catch the error in client code and rollback.  This isn't really an option, as our workflow process is just running the SQL script--and the "commit" needs to happen within the script rather than caller code (after testing the script, we run it without the transaction or rollback).
2. Use `DECLARE ... HANDLER FOR ...;` to rollback on error.  This looked promising, but appears to be only supported within a stored procedure (or similar) and therefore not suitable for one-off scripts.

What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: Use a programming language to execute the SQL queries. It can use exception handling to execute `ROLLBACK` when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar.  I noted that won't work in this situation, though, as it is part of a larger production data control workflow process.  We're simply calling the `mysql` command-line client and passing the script via stdin.  I feel like this should be possible via a script.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any control flow commands in plain SQL. If the connection closed it would abort automatically, but not if the script completes.

Comment: But how is the script completing if there is a failure?  I'm just baffled that an open transaction would ever commit without an explicit commit statement.

Comment: Good question. If the connection is closed without committing, it's supposed to rollback automatically.

Comment: Do you have any DDL statements in the script? Those force a commit.

Comment: No DDL, just selects/inserts/updates/deletes

Comment: Then I can't explain it. If it gets an error and aborts, it should roll back.

Comment: Make sure you use InnoDB or NDB engine. MyISAM does not support transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer to this -- apparently our MySQL instance is (somewhere) configured with `autocommit=1`.

So now our scripts look like:

```
select now();

set autocommit=0;
start transaction;

select 'data before any changes', ...;

<insert / update / delete statements>;

select 'data after changes', ...;

rollback;
```

And if the script runs into an error (whether that's a syntax problem or something like a key violation in the update statements), the transaction is rolled back!